# How can I speed-up the table reconstruction in MySQL when altering the schema?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, innodb

I have a relatively big MySQL InnoDB table (compressed), and I sometimes need to alter its schema (increasing column size or adding a field).

It takes around 1 hour for a 500 MB table with millions of rows, but the server doesn't seem to be very busy (CPU @5%, not much RAM used, and 2.5 MB/s as I/O).

The table is not used in production so there are no concurrent requests at the same time. There is only a primary index (on the first 5 columns) and one foreign key constraint.

Do you have any suggestion on how to speed-up the table alteration process?

Comment: Better hardware to run the server on? This is a hard question to answer without knowing anything about your setup.

Comment: According to the figures I gave, the hardware doesn't show any sign of weakness for this task...

Comment: Sorry, bad joke. This is rather curious, although 2.5MB/s is a little slow. You mean disk I/O speed, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the speed I can see in Resource monitor, for a 7.2k RPM x 2 RAID hard disk which can generally go much faster than this... Compression shouldn't take much time either, CPU-wise.

Comment: At 10k RPM, you should be getting _far_ more than 2.5MB/sec. You said this isn't a live table, but is the server used for other disk-related things?

Comment: No, it is not used for anything else in the mean time, and the progression is linear so it doesn't seem something could be interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing storage engine (to newer generation engines like [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/)) seems the way to go, until InnoDB is "fixed".

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to know the exact table and primary key/index definitions, and of lesser importance, the row count to the nearest million, although I would guess as the table is only 500mb it's probably less than 20 million rows.  Also, your approach to changing the table - are you creating a new schema and inserting into it, or using a alter table etc.

I've had success in this area before with approaches like

- changing the index key composition, adding a unique key
- dropping the indexes first, then changing the table, then adding the indexes back.  sometimes independent indexes can be a real performance killer if they are affected by the change.
- optimizing the table structure to remove unneeded or oversized columns
- separating out data (normally columns but you can vertically partition in some circumstances) that won't change from the core structure that might change, so you only churn a smaller part of your table

Comment: I am using ALTER TABLE; for example I just readded a foreign key that was unexpectedly dropped on a table, and it takes forever (this time a 3 GB table).
The table only consists of string/datetime/numeric types, and there is one INT foreign key.